# JDA charset проблемы

Tags: java, кодировка, discord, charset, discord-jda

Пишу бота для дискорда который связан с гугл таблицей и берет оттуда данные, так вот, когда он выводит данные из таблицы на русском, то они выводятся без проблем, но когда я пишу русскими буквами в бота, то по итогу он выводит символы.

```
EmbedBuilder helpEmbed = new EmbedBuilder();
helpEmbed.setTitle(" ***помощь по командам***");
```

> РїРѕРјРѕС‰СЊ РїРѕ РєРѕРјР°РЅРґР°Рј

А вот скриншот вывода русских букв из таблицы:

[image]

В *Intelij Idea* кодировка стоит UTF-8.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: у вас происходит перекодирование исходного текста (сохранённого в utf8), из cp1251 в utf8: `$ echo по | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8` как раз и выводит `РїРѕ`.

Comment: подскажите как это исправить на java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять кодировку в среде разработки на ANSI. Скорее всего, это поможет, обычно проблемы с выводом русских букв связаны именно с этим. При чём при кодировке ANSI будут корректно выводиться как и русские буквы, так и английские.